# Is it possible to count how many times a user has logged in MVC5 without a separate counter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET Identity is it possible to count how many times a user has performed the Logged in action without keeping a count in a separate data-table? For example I can set up a datatable sth like

```
[Table("LoginInfo")]
public class LoginCount()
{
public int UserId {get; set;}
public int counter{get; set;}
...
//other applicable parameters such as date, time, location etc.
}
```

But is this possible using the default Identity Datatables? Also is there a way to know if this is the first virgin login by the user just after registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely is possible.  If you're using the Entity Framework implementation, this is actually quite straightforward.

First, add an LoginCount to your application model.  Entity Framework will put the column in the `aspnet_users` table .

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int LoginCount { get; set; }
}
```

Now it's in your model, all you need to do is make sure it's incremented when your user signs in:

by adding in some code to the AccountController's login method:

```
user.LoginCount += 1;
UserManager.Update<ApplicationUser>(user);
```

It might look a little like:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                user.LoginCount += 1;
                UserManager.Update<ApplicationUser>(user);

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

No magic is required if you specifically want it to go to another table, just use the standard Code First loveliness in the ApplicationUser model.

Enjoy,

Paul